# Oracle - Hyphenated column in where clause

Tags: java, oracle, where-clause

Consider a table :

```
ID  COUNTRY_CODE
1   ab-cd-ef
2   gh-ef
3   cd-ab-pq-xy
```

And I need an sql query that selects the records which contain a specific country code.
The traditional `LIKE` approach works, of course:

```
select ID from TableName where COUNTRY_CODE like '%cd%';
```

The concern here is, this query would run over millions of records, thus increasing the cost of total operation. Due to the cost issues, nested tables is not an option here.

Note : The query can be parameterized with Java, if needed.

Is there any cost-effective way to handle such searchable columns?

Comment: If this table is not going to be updated very much you can create a Materialized View to create duplicate records for the COUNTRY_CODEs which have more than one country code. This way you can avoid using like to improve performance.

Comment: @STaefi The table contains millions of records and the table is ever growing. So duplication is not really an option here.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store lists as delimited strings. Either create a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY );

CREATE TABLE TableName__Country_Codes(
  id           NUMBER REFERENCES table_name ( id ),
  country_code CHAR(2),
  PRIMARY KEY ( id, country_code )
);
```

Then you could use

```
SELECT ID
FROM   TableName__Country_codes
WHERE  'cd' = COUNTRY_CODE;
```

Or use a nested table:

```
CREATE TYPE Char2List IS TABLE OF CHAR(2)
/

CREATE TABLE TableName(
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  Country_Code Char2List
) NESTED TABLE Country_code STORE AS Table_Name__Country_Codes;
```

Then you could use

```
SELECT ID
FROM   TableName
WHERE  'cd' MEMBER OF COUNTRY_CODE;
```

If you have to use a delimited string then your query should include the delimiters in the search expression:

```
SELECT ID
FROM   TableName
WHERE  '-' || COUNTRY_CODE || '-' like '%-cd-%';
```

Otherwise, if you have longer list elements then `%cd%` could match `cd` or `cda` or `bbcdbb`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The first approach means creating an entry for every (id,country_code) combination in another table; which does not seem advisable due to the size of the main table. 
The second approach, as I have already mentioned in the question, increases the operation cost tremendously.